# jQuery checking if input has value by function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I defined this function which checks if a input field is empty or not

```
function hasValue() {
    if ( !!$.trim( $(this).val() ) ) 
        return true;
}
```

It just works fine for filtering a jQuery Collection

```
$('#form').find( '.email' ).filter( hasValue );
```

But I also want to reuse the `hasValue()`-function for toggeling a class.

```
$('.input').change( function () {
    var empty = hasValue().apply( $(this) ); //throws an error
    // var empty = $(this).hasValue();       //doesn't work either
    $('#box').find('.required-tmp').toggleClass('required', empty );
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juste pass this to apply. And don't execute () before :

```
hasValue.apply(this);
```

If you want to have a better use of your function it must accept an element as parameter it's not a good pattern to use `this` like this. Prefer to pass the element in arguments

```
function hasValue(elem) {
    return !!$.trim($(elem).val());
}
```

And then the usage is the same for map :

```
$('#form').find( '.email' ).filter( hasValue );
```

And :

```
$('.input').change( function () {
    var empty = hasValue(elem); //throws an error
    $('#box').find('.required-tmp').toggleClass('required', empty );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.input').change( function () {
    var empty = hasValue.apply( $(this) ); //apply function should be used this way .
    // var empty = $(this).hasValue();       //doesn't work either
    $('#box').find('.required-tmp').toggleClass('required', empty );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using double negation in the hasValue method?

Secondly, use apply as:

```
var empty = hasValue.apply( this );
```

This will pass the element as the parameter which you can use there!

Thirdly, for checking whether the value exists, you can just use type check instead of trim as:

```
if(typeof $(this).val !== 'undefined'){
return true;
}
```

See if that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

fn.apply syntax should be like hasValue.apply( $(this) ) instead of hasValue().apply( $(this) )

May be that will solve your problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Charly